# Do WCF apps require,Windows Azure Service Bus Connect

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

Do WCF apps require that Windows Azure Service Bus Connect be installed on the server hosting the WCF services?

I am having the same issue described here [Blog with same error](http://mytechlifedays.wordpress.com/2011/12/27/configuration-binding-extension-system-servicemodelbindingsnettcprelaybinding-could-not-be-found/)

Comment: Only if you want to use Windows Azure Service Bus, I would think.

Comment: I get a error when my WCF app try's to connect to Dynamics CRM using claims and IFD.  I found a blog that said the Service Bus is required to connect to CRM.

Comment: It will help you to get a better answer if you provide more details in your question (like you did in your comment), and maybe a link to the blog you're referencing.   Your initial question is very broad.

Comment: My bad I have added the blog link above

Comment: Based on the blog, you need to add a reference to the specified DLL Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll; it doesn't appear to have anything to do with Azure specifically.